# What are the smallest planes running scheduled flights in Europe?

Tags: air-travel, europe

I’ve enjoyed flying in smaller planes on scheduled flights in the past (e.g. Aurigny’s old Trislanders). Are there any other scheduled flights in Europe in small (sub-20-seat) planes that are still running? I know about the Westray to Papa Westray flight already but feel free to include it in a list.

Comment: There are flights from the west coast of ireland to the Aran islands : http://aerarannislands.ie/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I did a search of all intra-European flights for tomorrow (12 Feb 2018) and came up with the following:

1. Hahn Air has a flight with a Cessna Citation (6 seats) scheduled between LUX and DUS
2. Loganair has several flights, as previously noted, mostly from KOI, NRL, and PPW on Britain-Norman Islanders (8 seats), as well as a number of flights around Scotland on 19-seat Twin Otters
3. Direct Flight has some Islanders with 9 seats flying out of LWK
4. Hebridean Air Services flies some Islanders from COL, TRE, and OBN
5. Isle of Scilly Skybus flies 16-seat Twin Otters from ISC to NQY and LEQ
6. BA's Scandinavian subsidiary, Sun Air of Scandinavia, flies 18-seat Avro J-31's between BGO and BLL
7. Aurigny flies 18-seat Dornier 228s between GCI and DNR
8. Flybe flies 19-seat Avro J-41's between CWL and VLY
9. Chalair flies Beechcraft Beech 1900D's with 19 seats around western France, mostly based out of BOD and NTE
10. Norlandair flies 19-seat Twin Otters in Iceland
11. AIS Airlines flies 19-seat Avro J-32's around Sweden, including ORB, GOT, and MMX
12. Aero VIP flies Avro J-32's around the Madeira Islands
13. Twin Jet flies Beechcraft Beech 1900D's with 19 seats around France based out of ORY, MRS, TLS, and LYS
14. SUE Orenberg flies 20-seat Let 410's around Russia.

That's just for one day. It's certainly likely that a lot of small routes with small planes don't fly everyday so I'm probably missing some.

Comment: In case you're wondering, the Hahn Air flight takes 45 minutes and costs $362. The train between the same two destinations takes 3h 45m and costs $85.

Comment: How did you search for all flights and then select the ones with the fewest seats or smallest planes?

Comment: @JonathanReez I wasn't suggesting that was a good option, just that it's something one could do... :)

Comment: @gerrit I work for an airline so I have access to some cool industry tools that let me do searches like that.

Comment: Note that Hahn Air isn't a traditional Airline. Their primary business is some kind of reselling / ticketing solution. They only operate a couple of pro-forma scheduled flights to retain their legal status as an airline, which they require for their primary business model.

Comment: AIS also flies in the south of Germany

Answer (score 9):

[OFD](http://www.fliegofd.de/) in Germany is offering regular flights (scheduled) between Emden and Borkum using a Cessna 172, with 2 pax max.

[Flight schedule](http://www.fliegofd.de/fileadmin/user_upload/OLT/PDF/Flugplan_OFD_Winter2017-18-web.pdf)

[The fleet](http://www.fliegofd.de/die-ofd/flotte.html)

Comment: The website also mentions some larger planes, how can I tell they use the Cessna 172 rather than one of their larger planes?

Comment: It is possible to ask them directly. However, by personal experience I can confirm that in most cases (in my case 100%) the 172 is serving the Emden - Borkum route. I do however know of some (rare) cases that another plane served that route though.

Answer (score 8):

Wikipedia lists a few dozen European [operators of Britten-Norman Islanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Britten-Norman_Islander_operators). Many of them are historical, but a few appear to currently fly scheduled routes with them:

- [Loganair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loganair) for Westray to Papa Westray
- [Isles of Scilly Skybus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isles_of_Scilly_Skybus)
- [Hebridean Air Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebridean_Air_Services)
- [FLN Frisia Luftverkehr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLN_Frisia_Luftverkehr)

Comment: FLN Frisia Luftverkehr even uses the Cessna 182T: http://www.airliners.net/photo/FLN-Frisia-Luftverkehr-Norddeich/Cessna-182T-Skylane/4746567?qsp=eJwtjEEKwkAMRe%2BStRtbEeyuXkAXXiBkPnZgbIckC0vp3U0Hd4/3%2BH8jWWbH119rBQ1kYJWJTlRZ%2BWM0bMRZS56P2PWX7hbNFvX7GiKxYxRBdaS/f2iCHgkm7eYdy3MA9NmY%2Bmv4lK0Wbh9wzoX2/QeG%2BS0L

Answer (score 6):

Norwegian company [Lufttransport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lufttransport) have a scheduled route between [Bodø Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bod%C3%B8_Airport) and [Værøy Heliport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A6r%C3%B8y_Heliport) using the [AgustaWestland AW139](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AgustaWestland_AW139) **helicopter** ([Værøy Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V%C3%A6r%C3%B8y_Airport) has been closed since a Twin Otter fatally crashed).  This helicopter has 15 seats.  It's a bit heavier and longer than some small fixed-wing aircrafts, but certainly much narrower.  Dimensions from Wikipedia:

> Length: 16.66 m (54 ft 8 in)
>   Width: 2.26 m (10 ft 0 in)
>   Height: 4.98 m (16 ft 4 in)
>   Empty weight: 3,622 kg (7,985 lb)

For comparison, the [Twin Otter DHC-6 Series 100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Canada_DHC-6_Twin_Otter#Specifications) has:

> Length: 15.77 m
>   Width: 19.8 m (wingspan)
>   Height: 5.9 m
>   Empty weight: 2,653 kg

The [Britten-Norman BN-2A Islander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britten-Norman_BN-2_Islander#Specifications_(BN-2A_Islander)) is shorter, lower, and lighter yet, but as a fixed-wing aircraft, remains much wider than the AgustaWestland.  For most definitions of "smaller", the Britten-Norman would win, but if you're looking for the most compact "plane", the AgustaWestland helicopter flying to Værøy wins.

Answer (score 3):

In Portugal there is a company, [Sevenair](https://fly.sevenair.com/pt/) that only operates a small airplane, a 19 seats [Dornier 228](https://dornier228.ruag.com/en). It flies across all Portugal, North to South, connecting 5 cities, Bragança, Vila Real, Viseu, Cascais, Portimão.

Answer (score 2):

According to [their website](http://www.finistair.fr/tarifs-et-horaires-de-la-ligne-brest-ouessant-ouessant-brest), Finist'air has flights most days of the week between Brest and Ushant on a [9-seat Cessna Caravan](http://www.finistair.fr/la-flotte-finistair).